# How to have custom urls that map to values in the db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I want to have urls like this:

www.example.com/topic1/...
www.example.com/topic2/...
www.example.com/topic3/...

And these should be served using the TopicController.

The values topic1, topic2, topic3, .. are coming from the table in the database (topics).

Is this possible?

What will my route look like then?  These topics will be added ofcourse, it isn't something that is static in nature.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
match '*a/' => 'topic#show' # assume the action is show
```

`params[:a]` will equal `topic1` etc.

Answer (score 0):

The closest solution I can think of would be to define a route such as

```
match "/topic/:name" => "topic#process_topic"
```

and the corresponding action in the TopicController

```
def process_topic
    @topic = Topic.find_by_name(params[:name])
    case @topic.name
        when topic1
            ...
        when topic2
            ...
    end
end
```

Comment: Or just 

   `match ":name" => "topic#process_topic"`

But then if you need other URLs apart from topics (www.example.com/something_that_is_not_topic) you'll have to place this route in the end of routes.rb